# Wake on WLAN on GNU/Linux on two machines: one works, the other does not

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, wireshark, wake-on-lan

I'm trying to set WoWLAN on two of my Linux machines, but I've only got it working in one of them. Following [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/configure-wireless-wake-on-lan-for-linux-wifi-wowlan-card/) tutorial, I've run:

```
sudo iw phy0 wowlan enable magic-packet
```

and also added it to /etc/rc.local so it runs on boot.

`iw phy0 wowlan show` yields:

```
WoWLAN is enabled:
* wake up on magic packet
```

So, when I send a magic packet to port 9 (also tried 7) with the correct MAC (yes, I've checked it several times) one of the machines will wake, but the other won't. The one that works works even outside LAN as I've set static IPs and port forwarding for both machines. But the other one won't wake no matter what. I've tried sending the packet to broadcast and also to the specific local IP, and I can see the magic packet on Wireshark when I send it to broadcast and also when I send it to the local IP and the pc is powered on, but not when it is off (I guess it does not have an IP yet).

I've also checked that the WLAN adapter (TP-Link Archer TX3000E) supports WoWLAN. Any ideas on what to check next?

Comment: Are they identical hardware? I think WOL needed firmware support to work. If they're different, maybe something similar is required for WoWLAN, and one of them doesn't have it?

Comment: Yes, they are different, but as I stated in the last line I've checked that the one that is not working yet supports WoWLAN.

Comment: By "firmware" I meant the motherboard's firmware options, not the NIC's.